# AngularJS item in ng-repeat as ng-model

Tags: angularjs, comparison, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have something like this:`{{item.bla|| item.bla2}}`

how can i put this in ng-model, i can't just do it like this:

```
input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="{{item.bla || item.bla2}}"
```

Comment: i have tried with value="{{item.bla|| item.bla2}}" but breeze doesn't track changes so i can't save normally in database

Comment: `<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="item.bla" />`. You cannot have two models bound to an `ng-model`. either put bla or bla2

Comment: but if  item.bla is null I want to put there item.bla2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help (assuming item is in scope):

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-init="model= item.bla || item.bla2" 
          ng-model="model" />
```